# Python 2.7: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm installing Python 2.7, open erp 7.0 and eclipse for programing and i met some error while running "openerp-server.py":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp-server.py", line 2, in <module>
import openerp
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
import addons
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\addons\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from openerp.modules import get_module_resource, get_module_path
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\modules\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\modules\graph.py", line 32, in <module>
import openerp.osv as osv
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\osv\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
import osv
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 30, in <module>
import orm
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 62, in <module>
import fields
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 47, in <module>
import openerp.tools as tools
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\tools\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from convert import *
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 51, in <module>
from translate import _
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\tools\translate.py", line 45, in <module>
import osutil
  File "F:\openerp-7.0-20130327-002325\openerp\tools\osutil.py", line 31, in <module>
import win32service as ws
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

please help me, thanks so much.

Comment: Is pywin32 on the PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I resolved the problem by re-installing Pywin32 for Windows:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/
2. Select http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe/download.
3. Install pywin32 by click pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe

I think problem is in installing pywin32 by the command line PIP.

Answer (score 1):

If you open it in dependencywalker it'll tell you what you're missing.  Sometimes you need to run dynamic mode b/c dependencies are loaded dynamically and will not be detected until you profile the application from within Dependency Walker

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

faq: http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `pywin32` through `pip`, then you need to **run the post install script**:

```
python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

More details in [pywin32 documentation](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

Answer (score -1):

Try installing [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), it comes with the required DLL.